# Winform WaitScreen implementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have the following WaitScreen class that shows a "please wait..." message when doing a background process:

```
public class WaitScreen
    {
        // Fields
        private object lockObject = new object();
        private string message = "Please Wait...";
        private Form waitScreen;

        // Methods
        public void Close()
        {
            lock (this.lockObject)
            {
                if (this.IsShowing)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.waitScreen.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(this.CloseWindow));
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                    }
                    this.waitScreen = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private void CloseWindow()
        {
            this.waitScreen.Dispose();
        }

        public void Show(string message)
        {
            if (this.IsShowing)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                this.message = message;
            }
            using (ManualResetEvent event2 = new ManualResetEvent(false))
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.ThreadStart));
                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start(event2);
                event2.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        private void ThreadStart(object parameter)
        {
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);
            ManualResetEvent event2 = (ManualResetEvent)parameter;
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            this.waitScreen = new Form();
            this.waitScreen.Tag = event2;
            this.waitScreen.ShowIcon = false;
            this.waitScreen.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.waitScreen.AutoSize = true;
            this.waitScreen.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.waitScreen.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
            this.waitScreen.ControlBox = false;
            this.waitScreen.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.waitScreen.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.waitScreen.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.waitScreen.Text = "";
            this.waitScreen.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.WaitScreenClosing);
            this.waitScreen.Shown += new EventHandler(this.WaitScreenShown);
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = this.message;
            label.AutoSize = true;
            label.Padding = new Padding(20, 40, 20, 30);
            this.waitScreen.Controls.Add(label);
            Application.Run(this.waitScreen);
            Application.ExitThread();
        }

        private void WaitScreenClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private void WaitScreenShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form form = (Form)sender;
            form.Shown -= new EventHandler(this.WaitScreenShown);
            ManualResetEvent tag = (ManualResetEvent)form.Tag;
            form.Tag = null;
            tag.Set();
        }

        // Properties
        public bool IsShowing
        {
            get
            {
                return (this.waitScreen != null);
            }
        }
    }
```

The way I use it is:

```
waitScreen = new WaitScreen();
waitScreen.Show("Please wait...");
```

I have a MainForm, inside a mainform I have a button, when clicked I show a Dialog that on load will get some data from database in a Backgroundworker. Before running the backgroundworker I show my **WaitScreen**.

Its working great but when the **WaitScreen** is displayed and If I click on the back Dialog then the **WaitScreen** is gone. So I want to block so I can't click on the back Dialog until the worker has finish and then I close my **WaitScreen**.

Any clue on how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this.  What you want is a modal dialog window which the user can't close which will close when a given task is finished.

You can make a standard class which derives from `Form` and implements a constructor or a property which you can pass a Task or a callback.

Here's what the code could look like in your `WaitScreen` form:

```
public partial class WaitScreen : Form
{
    public Action Worker { get; set; }

    public WaitScreen(Action worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (worker == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Worker = worker;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

Here's what your code would look like in the consumer of this `WaitScreen` form:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var waitScreen = new WaitScreen(SomeWorker))
        waitScreen.ShowDialog(this);
}

private void SomeWorker()
{
    // Load stuff from the database and store it in local variables.
    // Remember, this is running on a background thread and not the UI thread, don't touch controls.
}
```

You probably want to use FormBorderStyle.None in the WaitScreen so that the user can't close it.  Then the task is complete the WaitScreen will close itself and the caller will continue execution of code after the `ShowDialog()` call.  `ShowDialog()` blocks the calling thread.

Comment: Using your code, will first show the wait dialog and when finish the worker then the form is shown. I want to show the form dialog and then show the wait dialog. Any clue?

Comment: My example will show the wait dialog whenever you want.  Just move the `using` block that creates the WaitScreen and shows it as a dialog to where you want it.  If you want to open the dialog after a form is shown then move that code to the `Shown` event or `OnShown` method of the form in question.

Comment: Trevor how can I catch on parent form when the worker has finished? What I did was to add a DialogResult on the waitform and then just add if(..ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) { RunOnCompleteTask() }. Is that a good approeach?

Comment: I just debug and I get an error on the Factory this.Close();
The error is: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'frmWaitScreen' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: I don't follow...  As far as I understand you have a form which has a button, let's call it the MainForm.  When you click that button you want to show a new modal dialog as a popup, let's call it the PopupWindow.  So your MainForm creates a PopupWindow and calls `ShowDialog` on it to wait for it to be closed.  Yes, when you close the PopupWindow you can first specify `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.xxx` so that your PopupWindow can close with multiple types of results.  So your MainForm can check the return value of PopupWindow.  Your MainForm doesn't need to know about WaitScreen to do this

Comment: Good, I did that. Then Im right... the only thing pending is that error I commented... is it normal?

Comment: I edited a change to make it invoke it on the UI thread.  That will fix the error.

Comment: Wooow.... you are a genius :) I need to learn Task library its new to me.. where do you recommend me to start. Thanks a lot Trevor

Comment: Well first you want to make sure you understand the `Action` and `Func` generic delegates and lambdas.  Seeing big generic delegates like a `Func<Task,int,bool>` can be kinda scary at first.  Once you understand those, here is a pretty great blog on Tasks compared to other async methods: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html

Comment: Hi Trevor I just create a new question based on your code: here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172405/c-sharp-pass-parameter-to-action
Thanks a lot