# c# pass parameter to Action

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have the following code:

```
public partial class WaitScreen : Form
{
    public Action Worker { get; set; }

    public WaitScreen(Action worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (worker == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Worker = worker;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the consumer:

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var waitScreen = new WaitScreen(SomeWorker))
        waitScreen.ShowDialog(this);
}

private void SomeWorker()
{
    // Load stuff from the database and store it in local variables.
    // Remember, this is running on a background thread and not the UI thread, don't touch controls.
}
```

Now, I have to add a paramter to Action "SomeWorker", for example:

```
private void SomeWorker(Guid uid, String text)
    {
        // here will execute the task!!
    }
```

How can I pass the parameters **uid** and **text** to the Action?

Is it possible to make it generic so I can pass any parameter so It can work with any amount and types of params?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of situation I don't think you could use a `Action<Guid, string>` as I can't see how you would pass the parameters in to the new form in the first place. Your best option is use a anonymous delegate to capture the variables you want to pass in. You can still keep the function separate but you will need the anonymous delegate for the capture.

```
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    var text = someTextControl.Text;

    Action act = () => 
        {
            //The two values get captured here and get passed in when 
            //the function is called. Be sure not to modify uid or text later 
            //in the someButton_Click method as those changes will propagate.
            SomeWorker(uid, text)
        }
    using (var waitScreen = new WaitScreen(act))
        waitScreen.ShowDialog(this);
}

private void SomeWorker(Guid uid, String text)
{
    // Load stuff from the database and store it in local variables.
    // Remember, this is running on a background thread and not the UI thread, don't touch controls.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Action` is defined as `delegate void Action()`. Therefore, you cannot pass variables to it.

What you want is a `Action<T, T2>`, which exposes two parameters to be passed in.

Example usage.. feel free to apply it to your own needs:

```
Action<Guid, string> action = (guid, str) => {
    // guid is a Guid, str is a string.
};


// usage
action(Guid.NewGuid(), "Hello World!");
```